# Autofill UAC Dialog Win 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, uac, autofill

Hy there

I searched a lot on google, but couldn't find an answer. Maybe you have some ideas:

I have two account's on my pc, an admin account an user account. I usually work on my user account. When I want to run an application or install a new application, I have to enter the admin password in the UAC dialog.

Now I want to write a program, witch detects the Win 7 UAC Dialog, and autofill the admin password. I thought, I could detect the UAC dialog, and save the admin password i a buffer. Then I only have to paste the password in the UAC dialog.

Any ideas if this could work, and how I could detect the UAC dialog?

peace!

Comment: This should not be possible, there has to be all kind of protection layers active to prevent this. I once read an article where they discussed how the added some (crappy)special session code to prevent what you're asking for. Try and search for that.

Comment: You're trying to subvert **the entire purpose of the UAC dialog**, which is to **prevent a user from doing something that only an administrator is supposed to do**. Naughty, naughty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UAC dialog is DESIGNED to prevent this! Otherwise any virus could install itself without user input! Why are you doing this, instead of changing the UAC settings, or changing your account permissions?

Comment: Hy

I do not want to change the UAC settings. Instead of typing everytime the admin password, I want do this automatically. Therefore I thought I could save the admin password in a application, wich automatically fill's the UAC dialog when it appears.

But I already thought that this could be "impossible" ;-)

Thanky you a lot for your answers

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a pain, but the UAC dialog is a sandbox that other programs can't access. It was a good question though, and an interesting app you were trying to write! :)

Comment: I mean if you are the admin, you still have to click the UAC, fine, but now if you know the admin credentials then there should be a mechanism that definatelly gives UAC prompt but atleast uses sepcified credential details, so that user just click yes or no and it works, isn't this possible??